# body of email with hyperlink to windows-like path (from unix-like path)

Tags: html, python-3.x, hyperlink

I am writing a python script that, from within a Unix environment, should transfer some `.pdf` reports to a network drive accessed by other colleagues, who always access them on Windows. Upon transfer of the reports, my script sends them an email saying that the reports were transferred to a specific location and now I am trying to create a link in the body of the email that will redirect them to the location where the reports have been transferred to.

On Unix the reports are located at `/DriverName/the/rest/is/the/same`

Whereas the path on Windows looks like `\\driverName\department\subDepartment\the\rest\is\the\same`

So eventually I want my colleagues to be redirected to `\\driverName\department\subDepartment\the\rest\is\the\same` when they click on the text `/DriverName/the/rest/is/the/same` on the body of the email (shown below)

```
link_name = '/DriverName/the/rest/is/the/same'

body_html = f"<p>Reports of regular NIPT samples can be found at <a href='file:///\\driverName\department\subDepartment\the\rest\is\the\same'>{NIPTDIR_Hdrive}</a><p>"
```

My email gets sent and the text `/DriverName/the/rest/is/the/same` becomes clickable, though the path is not found when I click on it. I am quite sure the issue has to do with forward slashes `/` on Unix vs. backslashes `\` on Windows.

Does anyone know how I can 'translate' the (windows-like)path `\\driverName\department\subDepartment\the\rest\is\the\same` to a unix-like path, so that I can use in my python script?

Comment: Sounds like you just need to replace the backslashes with slashes and replace the first component of the path.

Comment: I swear up and down that I had tried that (and it did not work), it works now though, thanks for the comment